# Form a space $X$ by identifying the boundary of $M$ with $C$ by a homeomorphism. Compute all the homology groups of $X$.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $T$ denote the torus $S^1\times S^1$ and let $M$ denote the Möbius band. Let $C$ be a simple closed curve in $T$ which bounds a 2-disk. Form a space $X$ by identifying the boundary of $M$ with $C$ by a homeomorphism. Compute all the homology groups of $X$.

I am not sure how to start this problem. I tried Mayer-Vietoris by letting one set be an open set deformation retracting to a figure 8 and the other deformation retracting to a Möbius band and their intersection deformation retracting to a circle.  This unfortunately didn't work out too well though.  Any suggestions?

Comment: The disk bounded by $C$ isn't removed and so to use Mayer-Vietoris, you have to include the disk in one of the open sets.

Comment: @Daniel Rust I know.  I meant one of them deformation retracts to the projective plane.

Comment: Have you thought about trying to find a space homotopy equivalent to $X$? It seems like that disk could easily be contracted to a point.

Comment: I don't see how it could because of the boundary @Daniel Rust

Comment: Not sure at all how to do this!